# Design/Ideas needed for better utilization of space

Tags: web-app, tables, grid, best-practice, webforms

There is one grid-view in our web application. But as you can see, group and category are eating up the space.
[image]
Is there any better ideas for such layouts?
Even if there is total change in the layout, that will be fine.
I tried to search for better alternatives but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 9):

I think you should also try a card layout. For example:

[image: Card layout example]

This layout provides multiple benefits:

- **Aids quick scanning**

  - Cards are easier to scan compared to tables.
- **Easily adapt to small screens**

  - Cards will work better on mobile/smaller devices in this case compared to tables, as they can be organized to scroll in a single column.
- **Edit/delete buttons are positioned close to the items they modify**

  - In the original version, you'd notice that the edit/trash icons are a bit ambiguous. It is not clear what the icons will edit or remove. In general, [actions/buttons should be close to the things they act on](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/closeness-of-actions-and-objects-gui/).
- **Removes Icon cluster**

  - You don't have to show the icons in multiple rows. Using cards, icons can be shown (or emphasized) on hover and directly where they are needed.

Comment: Can you provide some reasoning? Why is this a better option? What does it solve that were issues in the original?

Answer (score 2):

You may try a tree hierachy style organization. Something like this :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCKN26.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>